# Why do I get this error - RunTimeException: Unable to instantiate activity?

Tags: android

My LogCat is saying:

```
java.lang.RunTimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.erikbalen.idealgaslawcalculator/com.erikbalen.idealgaslawcalculator.NumberActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity{ActivityThread.java:2121}
```

Here is my java file:

```
public class NumberActivity extends Activity {

EditText pressure = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPressure);
EditText temperature = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTemperature);
EditText volume = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextVolume);
TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSolve);
Button solve = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSolve);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_number);
    solve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            double pressureValue = Double.parseDouble(pressure.getText().toString());
            double temperatureValue = Double.parseDouble(temperature.getText().toString());
            double volumeValue = Double.parseDouble(volume.getText().toString());
            double r = 0.0821;
            double answerValue = (pressureValue*volumeValue)/(r*temperatureValue);
            answer.setText(Double.toString(answerValue));
        }
    });
}

}
```

Hopefully that is all you need. Let me know if you need additional code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the `findViewById()` calls

```
EditText pressure = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPressure);
EditText temperature = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTemperature);
EditText volume = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextVolume);
TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSolve);
Button solve = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSolve);
```

So they are after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_number);`

`findViewById()` will return `null` if it can't find the `View` in the layout. If there is no layout, there is no `View` to find. There is definitely no layout set when the `Activity` is first instantiated.

Comment: Oh thanks so much. I'm new to android so I am prone to making careless mistakes.

Comment: @ErikBalen you're welcome. Just to note, since `answer` and other Views are being accessed from inside an anonymous inner class, if you moved the entire declaration of each View to inside `onCreate()`, you will need to mark those references as `final`.